# SSL Key Pair Expired

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I am setting up SSL to use in Tomcat with a Java servlet.  I created a Keystore and imported a certificate, but now using "Keystore explorer", when I access the keystore it shows that the certificate is still okay and showing green but the key pair is showing red and is expired.

What do I do about this?

Thanks in advance

AJF

Comment: Key pairs don't expire. Certificates expire. There's something wrong with your observations, or the tool.

Comment: Okay EJP.  Thanks for the response.  I have made a new keystore now and it shows green in the keystore explorer tool